# AWS custom logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Environment – Two Different ec2 instances running tomcat separately.

Requirement – If there is any Error in logs – we should get an alert.

Implementation –

We implemented AWS customer logging for this which is successfully sending alerts on the Error Pattern Matching.
It automatically created a log groups – “/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out”.

Under this log group – there are two log streams – two instances separately showing.

Problem –

Now I want separate alarm for separate instances

Problem is when I create an alarm – it does not let me choose the instance. It takes both instance by default, which means one alarm – monitoring both instances simultaneously. And sending alert without mentioning instance name. so it is difficult to find which instance has actually sent alert.

And the second problem is - we created few log metrics for testing – like on keyword – info – which we want to delete and not able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the **CloudWatch Logs** functionality that permits automated sending of log files from an EC2 instance (or elsewhere) to the CloudWatch service. CloudWatch Logs can then be configured to look for strings in the log files, which will trigger the recording of metrics.

**To create separate alarms for separate instances**, each EC2 instance should be configured to use a different CloudWatch Log stream. The CloudWatch Logs agent takes a *Destination Log Group name*.

See: [Quick Start: Install and Configure the CloudWatch Logs Agent on an Existing EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)

As for the metrics that you wish to delete, **it is not possible to delete metrics from Amazon CloudWatch**. However, metrics will automatically disappear after 14 days.